# How to Use ObjectifyServices to get the Model Id instead of Id in java?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, objectify

I want to return the Id of Entity instead of EntityMOdel. The following function will return the List of `MyModel`, However, I want to return List, where this list will be the ids of filter `MyModel`.

```
public static List<MyModel> getUpdatedMyModel(Long beforeTime) {
    return ofy().load().type(MyModel.class).filter("updatedAt >", beforeTime).list() 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a keys-only query:

```
final List<Key<MyModel>> keys = ofy().load()
        .type(MyModel.class)
        .filter("updatedAt >", beforeTime)
        .keys()
        .list();
```

You can transform this to just the ids with Java streams:

```
final List<Long> ids = ofy().load()
        .type(MyModel.class)
        .filter("updatedAt >", beforeTime)
        .keys()
        .list()
        .stream()
        .map(Key::getId)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, it's generally a bad habit to pass around Long values in your app. The `Key<?>` objects are typesafe.